# Getting exception error in passing function of doGet block

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-listeners

I am getting error in the below code when i am passing value to some other function,all error are related to exception generates,but i am not able to sort out,as i am working in eclipse it suggest **trycatch** block in **findMeaning** passing function but this was not worked for me I got output that was null after taking there suggestion, please see the code below

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException
    {


        String searchWord= req.getParameter("txtweb-message");
        if (searchWord == null|| searchWord.isEmpty())
            sendResponse(resp,"for decrypt msg write @secretmsg.de (msg)");
        else

                findMeaning(resp,searchWord);//getting exception error here


           }
```

passing value to function,

```
private void findMeaning(HttpServletResponse resp,String plainText) throws MalformedURLException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
    InvalidKeySpecException, 
    NoSuchPaddingException, 
    InvalidKeyException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
    UnsupportedEncodingException, 
    IllegalBlockSizeException, 
    BadPaddingException{ 





        /**
         * 
         * @param secretKey Key used to encrypt data
         * @param plainText Text input to be encrypted
         * @return Returns encrypted text
         * 
         */
        String secretKey = "ezeon8547";


            //Key generation for enc and desc
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);        
             // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

            //Enc process
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);      
            String charSet="UTF-8";       
            byte[] in = plainText.getBytes(charSet);
            byte[] out = ecipher.doFinal(in);
            String encStr=new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(out);

              sendResponse(resp, "Pincode city:" +encStr);

         /**     
         * @param secretKey Key used to decrypt data
         * @param encryptedText encrypted text input to decrypt
         * @return Returns plain text after decryption
         */



    }
```

Comment: where and what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

your calling function throwing

```
throws MalformedURLException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
```

so when you are calling this function your calling code should declare or catch such exception.
its said as exception propogation.

Comment: how to do that @sanjay rajjadi please elaborate

Comment: append this line public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException, MalformedURLException, NoSuchAlgorithmException

Comment: where to append here in this code or i have to replace this code with above one public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException @sanjay rajjadi

Comment: no still shows error if i try to remove error it accepts     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException, MalformedURLException  {
 but still throw error in function findMeaning @sanjay rajjadi